# How can I get into the BIOS with a broken keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bios, laptop-repair

My laptop (an Acer Aspire 5630) has the <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, and <kbd>esc</kbd> keys broken. I need to change the boot sequence so I can install an operating system but I can't get into the BIOS to tweak that parameter.

What can I do?

I thought about resetting the CMOS hoping that at the next boot It'll force me into bios to check wrong parameters.

Maybe also flashing a new BIOS (if it's possible from the operating system) could trigger me at the next boot to the BIOS to tweak the boot sequence parameter.

Any ideas?

**Other Details**

- USB keyboard is not working before operating system boot
- No PS/2 ports on board

Comment: have you tried plugging in a usb keyboard ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it: yes.
Of course not working :(

Comment: ps
no ps/2 port on board

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Replace the keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001QWW1IK).

$12 problem solved.  Stop looking for workarounds and fix the real problem.

Comment: you got quite a point...
I'm just scared thinking about small torx screws anywhere :)

Comment: I think he's saying that he doesn't have the USB keyboard option turned on in the BIOS so the integrated one is all he can use.

Comment: @Blomkvist - I think you're right, which is why I upvoted this answer.  He HAS to replace the internal keyboard, there's really no (easy or reasonable) way around it at this point.